# $S_3/N \cong Z_2$

Tags: abstract-algebra

The normal subgroup of $S_3$ according to an example is

$$N= \left \{ \begin{pmatrix}1& 2& 3 \\ 1 &2 &3  \end{pmatrix}
          ,\begin{pmatrix}1& 2 &3 \\ 2 &3& 1  \end{pmatrix}
         ,\begin{pmatrix}1& 2& 3 \\  3 &1& 2  \end{pmatrix} \right\} $$

Show that $S_3/N  \cong Z_2$

---

---

All I have as of now is that the right cosets but not sure how.

I understand how the order of the quotietn is 2 since $|S_3/N|=3!/3= 3*2*1/3=2$. I am trying to find the elements and then show how it is isomorphic.

---

Comment: Any group of order $2$ is necessarily $Z_2$.

Comment: Yeah! I get the Isomophism now but I dont understand how to get the two permutation matrices in the quotient group

Comment: @Ugo Which two permutation matrices? The two elements of $S_3/N$ are $N$ and $gN$ where $g\notin N$.

Comment: Two partitions are the element of the quotient group one is $N$ and the other outside of $N$. g could be $\begin{pmatrix}1 &2& 3 \\ 1& 3 &2 \end{pmatrix}$. I multiplied N by $g$ and I get the partition. The elements are not permutation but a partition or set of permutations which I did not understand before

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since $N=\{1,(123),(132)\}$ has index $2$ in $S_3$, it is a normal subgroup with quotient group consisting of two elements. Hence we have
$$
S_3/N\cong C_2.
$$
Of course, another question is, to identify the element of order $2$ in the quotient with a coset. The coset here is $gN$ for any $g\in G\setminus N$.